# cx_freeze app not launching

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I was able to build the app I want to create with cx_Freeze, except when I launch it, the app appears on the task bar for a split seconds and immediately quits itself. I am using a Mac, python 3.4.3 (I also have a 2.7 version of my code), and  cx_Freeze-4.3.4.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @AlexPan which code? My setup.py? My regular code works if you were to launch it out of shell or terminal.

Comment: add in your questions. `all import line`